# E-mail Formatting Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, email, plsql

I need some help with this procedure. I need to include in a single e-mail the whole result of the select on the first Cursor (C1).
The way the procedure is working now, it sends an e-mail for each row found. The result is, if the cursor finds 100 rows, 100 e-mails will be sent, and I don't want that to happen, I need the 100 rows in a single e-mail, following the "V_MENSAGEM" structure.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PR_ENVIA_EMAIL_LOTE_ESTOQUE IS


V_REMETENTE     VARCHAR2(50) := 'servidor@oracle.com.br';
V_SAUDACAO      VARCHAR2(50);
V_ASSUNTO       VARCHAR2(200);
V_ASSINATURA    VARCHAR2(100);
V_MENSAGEM      VARCHAR2(6000);
V_COD_ERRO      NUMBER(2);
V_MSG_ERRO      VARCHAR2(1);
TDESCRI_ARMAZEM VARCHAR2(50);
TDESCRI         VARCHAR2(60);

BEGIN 

    FOR C1 IN (SELECT TBLOTE.NNOTFIS  NOTA_FISCAL, 
                      TBLOTE.CLOTE    LOTE, 
                      TBARMAZ.TDESCRI ARMAZEM,  
                      TBNOTF.DDTFATU  DATA_FAT_NF,  
                      TBLOTE.DRECEBTO DATA_RECEBTO, 
                      TBLOTE.CPRODUT  COD_PRODUTO, 
                      TBPRODU.TDESCRI PRODUTO,
                      TBLOTAR.QQTESTQ QTD_ESTOQUE,
                      Decode(TBLOTE.F_ARMAZENAGEM, 'S', 'SIM', 'N', 'NÃO') ARMAZENAGEM,
                      Decode(TBLOTE.SLTENCR, 'S', 'SIM', 'N', 'NÃO')  ENCERRADO,
                      TO_DATE(Sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') - TO_DATE(TBLOTE.DRECEBTO, 'dd/mm/yyyy')DIAS_EM_ESTOQUE
                 FROM TBLOTE,
                      TBLOTAR,
                      TBPRODU,
                      TBARMAZ,
                      TBNOTF
                WHERE TBLOTE.CPRODUT       = TBPRODU.CPRODUT
                  AND TBLOTE.CLOTE         = TBLOTAR.CLOTE
                  AND TBLOTAR.CARMAZE      = TBARMAZ.CARMAZE
                  AND TBLOTE.NNOTFIS       = TBNOTF.NNOTFIS
                  AND TBLOTE.CEMPRES       = TBNOTF.CEMPRES
                  AND TBLOTE.SLTENCR       = 'N'
                  AND TBLOTE.F_ARMAZENAGEM = 'S'
                  AND TBLOTE.NNOTFIS IS NOT NULL 
                  AND TO_DATE(Sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') - TO_DATE(TBLOTE.DRECEBTO, 'dd/mm/yyyy') >= 165
                  ORDER BY DIAS_EM_ESTOQUE DESC)
       LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LENDO '||C1.NOTA_FISCAL|| ' - ' ||C1.LOTE|| ' - ' ||C1.ARMAZEM|| ' - ' ||C1.PRODUTO|| ' - Dias em Estoque: ' || C1.DIAS_EM_ESTOQUE);

   BEGIN
      IF TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24')) < 12 THEN
         V_SAUDACAO:= 'Bom Dia!';
      ELSIF TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24')) >= 12 AND
            TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24'))    <  18 THEN
            V_SAUDACAO:= 'Boa tarde!';
      ELSE
         V_SAUDACAO:= 'Boa noite!';
      END IF;
        
        
        V_ASSUNTO := 'AVISO: Lotes em estoque.';

        V_MENSAGEM := ' Os seguintes lotes ja estao há pelo menos 165 dias em nosso estoque, favor verificar: '||CHR(10)||CHR(10);

      V_MENSAGEM := V_MENSAGEM ||'Nota Fiscal : '||C1.NOTA_FISCAL||CHR(10)||
                                 'Lote : '||C1.LOTE||CHR(10)||
                                 'Armazem : '||C1.ARMAZEM||CHR(10)||
                                 'Dt. Faturamento : '||To_Date(C1.DATA_FAT_NF, 'DD/MM/YYYY')||CHR(10)||
                                 'Dt. Recebimento : '||C1.DATA_RECEBTO||CHR(10)||
                                 'Produto : '||C1.PRODUTO||CHR(10)||CHR(10)|| 
                                 'Qtd. em Estoque : '||C1.QTD_ESTOQUE||CHR(10)||
                                 'Dias em Estoque : '||C1.DIAS_EM_ESTOQUE||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||
                                 'Estamos a disposiçao.'||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||
                                 'Att. '||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||
                                 'Departamento de T.I'||CHR(10)||
                                 '---';

      V_MENSAGEM := V_SAUDACAO||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||
                    V_MENSAGEM||
                    CHR(10)||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||
                    V_ASSINATURA;
                                                    

       FOR C2 IN (SELECT EMAIL_USUARIO
                        FROM   TBEMAIL_INTERNO
                        WHERE  F_LOTE_ESTOQUE = 'S'
                        AND    F_EXCLUSAO_LOGICA   = 'N')
              LOOP
              
            
                PR_ENVIA_EMAIL(V_REMETENTE,
                               C2.EMAIL_USUARIO,
                               V_ASSUNTO,
                               V_MENSAGEM,
                               V_COD_ERRO,
                               V_MSG_ERRO);
                                                            
       END LOOP;                                   

    END;
 
 END LOOP ;           
    

      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('ATENÇÃO: ERRO AO CHAMAR ROTINA PR_ENVIA_EMAIL_LOTE_ESTOQUE: '||SQLERRM);


END PR_ENVIA_EMAIL_LOTE_ESTOQUE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're sending the email for every iteration of the loop through cursor C1 is that the loop through C2 (the one that sends the email) is **inside** the loop through C1. This change should fix your issue:

```
...
      V_MENSAGEM := V_SAUDACAO||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||
                    V_MENSAGEM||
                    CHR(10)||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||
                    V_ASSINATURA;                                                    
    END;
 END LOOP ;  
 FOR C2 IN (SELECT EMAIL_USUARIO
                  FROM   TBEMAIL_INTERNO
                  WHERE  F_LOTE_ESTOQUE = 'S'
                  AND    F_EXCLUSAO_LOGICA   = 'N')
        LOOP
          PR_ENVIA_EMAIL(V_REMETENTE,
                         C2.EMAIL_USUARIO,
                         V_ASSUNTO,
                         V_MENSAGEM,
                         V_COD_ERRO,
                         V_MSG_ERRO);                                       
 END LOOP; 
EXCEPTION

...
```

Comment: That kinda helped me! I didn't receive a single e-mail for each row found by the select statement. However, I just received one e-mail with one of the many rows found, this single e-mail should contain information about every row found, as if you were concatenating data found. I don't know if I was too clear about it, sorry :/

Comment: That is because every iteration you're overwriting V_MENSAGEM in the statement ```V_MENSAGEM := ' Os seguintes lotes ...```. Change that to ```V_MENSAGEM := V_MENSAGEM ||' Os seguintes lotes ...```

Comment: That worked just fine, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to help :)